# Valentina Studio and postgres configuration

Tags: database, postgresql, valentina-studio

I am trying to set up postgressql with valentina studio. My postgres access doesn't require password but my Vstudio requires a password and its not letting me connect to my postgres databases. Does anyone know what can be done here? I am using ubuntu. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: I have connections with empty passwords, VStudio doesn't require password for connections, can you clarify what connection method you are using and what version of Vstudio is installed